# onCreate() in service never called

Tags: android, android-service

I want to implement a service that handle screen on/off. To do so, I have created `BootReceiver` that is called at boot completed and within I start my service.

However, `OnCreate` is never called, why?.

When I print the log of the program I never see the `onCreate`'s log even though I see the `onStartCommand`'s log. How is this possible? Please help me to understand this.

This is `BootReceiver` that is called in the very beginning:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.w("TAG", "BootReceiver");

        Intent service = new Intent(context, ScreenListenerService.class);
            context.startService(service);

    }

}
```

This is the service:

```
public class ScreenListenerService extends Service {


    public void OnCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Log.w("TAG", "ScreenListenerService---OnCreate ");
    }


     @Override
     public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            Log.w("TAG", "ScreenListenerService---onStart ");


        }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

And the manifest:

```
<service android:name=".ScreenListenerService"></service>

        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_EXTERNAL_APPLICATIONS_AVAILABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Use `@Override` annotations to catch these things, as you have on `onStartCommand()` and `onBind()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change:

```
public void OnCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Log.w("TAG", "ScreenListenerService---OnCreate ");
}
```

to:

```
public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    Log.w("TAG", "ScreenListenerService---OnCreate ");
}
```

Java is case sensitive, so `OnCreate()` != `onCreate()`

Comment: Could you please check my other question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265667/android-broadcastreceiver-is-never-called

Answer (score 0):

wrong spelling in `onCreate`. You are using OnCreate instead of `onCreate`. To get rid of this kind of mistake it is better to use `@override` annotation everytime you override a method